# Arduino webserver using GPRS

Tags: web, arduino, gsm, gprs

I am trying to make Arduino web server using [SIM300](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMCom#History). I want to control my Arduino through the web from any where around the world. Controlling through [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) is easy, but it does not guarantee that an SMS will reach it on time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by reading this. http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield

On the other hand I can advise you that running a webserver on an Arduino is kinda high end for a low end board. (although not impossible of course)

One would more easily use a Raspb Pi  or a beagle bone for this.

If you would implement a webserver on your arduino it runs that server sequentially next to the code you want it to execute. (so when it is by example steering a servo the webserver will not work)